# Bazel issue while building a pip package for TensorFlow with CPU-only support

Tags: tensorflow, pip, bazel

guys! I am trying to build a pip package for tensorflow by following steps in [Installing TensorFlow from Sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources/%22Installing%20TensorFlow%20from%20Sources%22).After invoking the following command:`$ bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`,however,I got these as follow:

```
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file
'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': Error do
wnloading [http://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive
/aac19edc557aec9b603cd7ffe359401264ceff0d.tar.gz, https://github.com/bazelbuild/
rules_closure/archive/aac19edc557aec9b603cd7ffe359401264ceff0d.tar.gz] to /priva
te/var/tmp/_bazel_WilliamHuang/75f5fa598a7d55b225c399e7e82a3908/external/io_baze
l_rules_closure/aac19edc557aec9b603cd7ffe359401264ceff0d.tar.gz: All mirrors are
down: [].
INFO: Elapsed time: 58.126s
```

My ./configure as follow:

```
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MKL support? [y/N] n
No MKL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when 
bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? 
[y/N] n
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? 
[y/N] n
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler 
(experimental)? [y/N] n
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with VERBS support? [y/N] n
No VERBS support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] n
No OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] n
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
```

And my bazel version is 0.4.5

```
Build label: 0.4.5-homebrew
```

Hope you guys could please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by setting a proxy before `$ bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` as

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy_ip:port  (e.g. export http_proxy=http://10.110.0.25:8888)
export https_proxy=http://proxy_ip:port
```